# Add an html file to the build version of react

Tags: html, reactjs, dom

I have a landing file which is in pure HTML. (`landing.html`)
I want the main URL of the website to be this file and the rest of the URLs to go in the React app.

For example:

```
example.com -> landing.html
example.com/app -> react app 
example.com/login -> react app
```

As I said, I want the main URL to read the `landing.html`.
But the rest of the app should read the build version of React.

**If it's possible** i want it to be a part of the React app and not adding it directly in build folder. After running build it should be automaticly in build folder so basicly kinda implicitly to be a part of react app.

One more thing I dont want to convert it to jsx.

How can I implement this ?

Comment: `I dont want to convert it to jsx` why???

Comment: @NeERAJTK the HTML file has some scripts and head tags. i want to treat it like something outside of React. I did some research, but there wasn't a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the landing page use

````
var __html = require('./template.html');
var __html = require('./template.html');
var template = { __html: __html };

React.module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template} />
    );
  }
});``` 

on / route and other react components use on app and login route
````

Comment: I have already tried this out, but the HTML didn't render correctly. I get this ESLint error : React.createClass is deprecated since React 15.5.0, use the npm module create-react-class insteadeslintreact/no-deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I researched a bit and found two solution for it.

**First** : Using [multipage app](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) feature in Vite.

**Second**: confining nginx on server for this feature. (I didn't do the configuration someone else did, but it worked)